# Not able to display special characters properly in a JSP page

Tags: jsp

I need to display following special characters in a table TD (exclude the back slash in between < symbol and forward slash),

**1)** `'/<\/@/test#/$/&/)'`

But, the browser is able to display only '/
i.e, data is getting truncated.

The above issue occurs only when < and / chars occur contiguously.

That is, following works as there is no succeeding forward slash / after the < symbol

**2)** `'/<@/test#/$/&/)'`

I am using java code to escape the other special chars.
I am able to successfully replace < with ampersand lt; but how to replace a forward slash / only when < and / appear together.

Please help me

Sorry, even in this website you cannot see what i need to achieve, hence in Point 1 exclude the back slash (I need to display without the backslash, for ur understanding i have put it). I cannot post images as i am a new user.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you can use the backtick (`) (don't confuse it with the single quote) to escape code/HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everthing which get sent by JSP is by default treated as HTML by the webbrowser. The `<` indicates start of a HTML tag and thus the webbrowser will parse it as such (and eventually fail due to a syntax error).

You want to escape those HTML special characters like `<`, `>`, `&` and `"`.

```
&lt; will be displayed as <
&gt; will be displayed as >
&amp; will be displayed as &
&quot; will be displayed as "
```

If it is dynamic text, this is best to be done with [JSTL `<c:out>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:out value="${bean.text}" />
```

Of if you want to set a HTML attribute, the [JSTL `fn:escapeXml()` function](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) is nicer.

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<input type="text" value="${fn:escapeXml(bean.text)}" />
```

Comment: Simple solution but very powerful. Thank you very much it solved my issue. I didn't expect such a fast response. Thanks a million times.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, just want to print "kΩ" but it's not printing as it is, rather it shows "kâ¦". When I tried your solution it gives 'Invalid character string used in text string', please help me fix this, thanks.

Comment: @Java.beginner: that problem has an entirely different cause and needs to be solved entirely different. Hint: "character encoding".

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, its working after I set to "pageEncoding="utf8"", thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work on JSP by adding this directive to the page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```