# JavaScript Escaping Form Values

Tags: javascript, jsp, escaping

I know there are a lot of JavaScript escaping questions, but nothing seemed to fit my needs.

I have textarea elements being dynamically displayed on a JSP. In the case of invalid form submits, I need to repopulate these fields with the values the user entered. I am doing this like so (note: simplified version):

```
var textareaBox = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
if (textareaBox) {
    textareaBox.value = '${myForm.myValue}';
}
```

Everything works fine until the user enters a value in the box that contains special characters. I've tried using the `escape` and `unescape` JavaScript functions individually and combined to no avail.

Does anyone know how I can handle these special character values? Note that I obviously do not want the escaped text in the textarea as this would not look good to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)'s `<c:out>` tag to escape it and assign it as `innerHTML` of the text area:

```
textareaBox.innerHTML = '<c:out value="${myForm.myValue}" />';
```

But why don't you just display it in textarea's body directly without the need for JS?

```
<textarea id="myTextArea"><c:out value="${myForm.myValue}" /></textarea>
```

The `<c:out>` (and its EL function counterpart `fn:escapeXml()`) escapes XML special characters.

#### See also:

- [Not able to display special characters properly in a JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598565/not-able-to-display-special-characters-properly-in-a-jsp-page)

Comment: Using this solution, the text `Here's a special character.` ends up being `Here&#039;s a special character.`. As mentioned, this is not user friendly.

Comment: Oh, and not using just the body because as I mentioned they are dynamically added (different textareas appear/disappear depending on some drop down selections, etc).

Comment: Output it in the textarea's body directly then. As to the dynamicness, if you had a problem with outputting it in the textarea's body directly, then you would have exactly the same problem with JS, so I don't see the real problem.

Comment: How do you mean? It has to be done after the page loads. It just how it is for the situation. It must be done via JavaScript.

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `value` then. But how so, after the page loads? JSP/JSTL/EL runs at the same moment as the page loads, regardless of it's printing HTML or JS code.

Comment: The area where the textareas are to be displayed is loaded before the textareas are actually added, etc. That's what I was trying to say.

Comment: The innerHTML worked. If you update your answer to say `textareaBox.innerHTML = '<c:out value="${myForm.myValue}" />';` I'll mark it as correct.