# Populating Textareas with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, dom, textarea, jstl

This is an extension of a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346198/javascript-escaping-form-values) I asked. I ran into some additional issues.

I am loading a form with dynamic textarea boxes. Don't ask why, but I need to populate these fields using JavaScript (has to deal with AJAX stuff, etc). To simplify things, let's just say my textarea has a name of "myTextarea" and I want to populate with a request parameter "myRequestParam". So I'd want to do something like:

```
updateTextareaText("myTextarea", "${myRequestParameter}");
```

From my previous question, I've found that this solves some issues:

```
updateTextareaText("myTextarea", unescape('<c:out value="${myRequestParam}" />'));
```

I have tried a number of different implementations for `updateTextareaText`, but nothing seems to work. I need to handle both newlines and special characters.

**Try #1**

```
function updateTextareaText(textareaElementName, newText) {
    var textareaBox = document.getElementsByName(textareaElementName)[0];
    textareaBox.innerHTML = newText;
}
```

**Try #2**

```
function updateTextareaText(textareaElementName, newText) {
    var textareaBox = document.getElementsByName(textareaElementName)[0];
    textareaBox.value = newText;
}
```

**Try #3**

```
function updateTextareaText(textareaElementName, newText) {
    var textareaBox = document.getElementsByName(textareaElementName)[0];

    var existingNodes = textareaBox.childNodes;
    if (existingNodes.length > 0) {
        textareaBox.removeChild(existingNodes[0]);
    }

    var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(newText);
    textareaBox.appendChild(newTextNode);
}
```

All of the above loose newlines and/or displays some special characters as their escaped values. I've been using the following `myRequestParam` value for testing:

```
Test

Newline and Special `~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:";'<>?,./
```

Does anyone know the correct way to handle all of the different cases? As a side note, the `myRequestParam` values are populated from the DB and are returning newlines as `\r\n` which I have been escaping as `%0A`, but I am not sure if that's what I should be doing. The JavaScript originally wouldn't handle the `\r\n` (it would complain about unterminated strings, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539696/how-to-handle-newlines-in-a-struts-form-that-relies-on-javascript) that I submitted. The trick was to remove the escaping from the backside and the whole `escape` and `<c:out>` stuff and instead use an EL function that utilizes `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery:

```
$('#textAreaId').val('MyValue');
```

or

```
$('#textAreaId').html('MyValue');
```

Guess it would do the trick.

Comment: My company has not approved jQuery use. Out of curiosity, does jQuery allow fetching by name (not id)?

Comment: Ohh, such a pain! jQuery its quite awesome and saves a lot of time... And YES, in  jQuery You can fetch any item by id, name, class, content... take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

In a limited and local try it worked for me with your #2 function (only tried that one).

header: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

javascript: updateTextareaText("txtarea", "Test\n\nNewline and Special `\~!@#$%\^\&*()_+-={}|[]\:\";'<>?,.//\näöüÄÖÜß");

So the String you get is probably not escaped (\', \&, etc.), in which case Apache's StringEscapeUtils in Commons Langs helps ( http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29 ).

Other than that, you would have to do a conversion for this javascript case by replacing ' with \' and so on... not pretty.