# JSP. How to get copyrght symbol from bean getter

Tags: java, jsp, copyright-display

I have a bean which has String property, which stores copyright symbol

```
private String copyright = "my company &#169; 2016 All rights reserved";

public String getCopyright() {
     return this.copyright;
}
```

The problem, that jspx page don't display copyrigh symbol. It jus displays text like this:

```
my company &#169; 2016 All rights reserved
```

How can I return text which contains copyright symbol in jsp?

---

This is how I get that bean property in jsp page

In this case copyright symbol is not displayed

```
<TD align="center" style=" font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; ">
     #{copyrightBean.copyrights}  
</TD>
```

Now copyright symbol is dispalyed, but it didn;t come from bean:

```
<TD align="center" style=" font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; ">
     &#169;
</TD>
```

Comment: how do you use the copyright string inside the JSP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to display special characters properly in a JSP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598565/not-able-to-display-special-characters-properly-in-a-jsp-page)

Comment: Which templating tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` in the string is escaped when printed in the JSP page (the HTML will contain a string `"my company &amp;#169; 2016..."`).

Therefore the string should not escape the copyright symbol:

```
private String copyright = "my company © 2016 All rights reserved";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be HTML escaping your call to the bean. If you view the source of your HTML, you'll see

```
 &amp;#169;
```

There are two solutions:

- Use the UTF-8 character instead (simplest): ©
- Don't auto-escape your template content, the exact way will depend on the templating engine you are using